# Why the iframe link not showing

Tags: html, css, iframe

When i copy and pasted the link from   in google it changes (no idea why it changes )  and showing it result . But i can't figure out why it doesn't show it result with existing link .

```css
div.sidebar {
  float: right;
  border: 10px #0000ee;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  font-face: times;
  color: #660099;
  text-align: left;
}

.sbarTitle {
  float: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Times, serif;
  font-size: 115%;
  color: #660099;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <span class="sbarTitle">NOTE: </span> For a much more detailed exploration of this idea, please see my piece,<i> Soul Friends: A Wiccan / 
    Jesus-Based Spirituality</i>, in the book:
  <p></p> <br>
  <TABLE align="left" width="130">
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <iframe src="https://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm? 
    lt1=_blank&bc1=FFFFFF&IS2=1&nou=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=gointhbe- 
    20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=tf_til&asins=0738721913" style="width:120px;height:240px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To load the iframe conent with jquery get as the following code:

```js
$.get("https://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=FFFFFF&IS2=1&nou=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=gointhbe-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=tf_til&asins=0738721913", function (response){ 
var html = response;
var html_src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + html;
$("#iframeId").attr("src" , html_src);
});
```

```css
div.sidebar{
float: right;
border: 10px #0000ee;
width: 30%;
font-size: small;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #CCCCFF;
color: #660099;
text-align: left;}

.sbarTitle {float: center; font-family: Georgia, Palatino, Times, serif; font-size:115%; color: 
#660099; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
<span class="sbarTitle">NOTE: </span> 
For a much more detailed exploration of this idea, please see my piece,<i> Soul Friends: A Wiccan / 
Jesus-Based Spirituality</i>, in the book: 
<p></p>  <br> 
<TABLE align="left" width="130">
<TR>
<TD>
<iframe id="iframeId" style="width:120px;height:240px;" 
scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . Main problem is i have to do this by only HTML and CSS .  There is no option to use JS or Jquary in "sitesell CMS" . Is it possible ?

Comment: Sure but I don’t know why it’s not working for your link that’s why I proposed to use the jquery